# How to process and return information in API (JSON to Python and back)?

Tags: python, json, api

I'm a relatively newbie programmer trying to use an API that gives JSON objects when you send get requests.

So I decided to do the following:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
import json

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.ripple.com/v1/accounts/rssc7gemsZBsseHxyb5NmjfYpJD6aUJirq/balances')
html = response.read()
```

I discovered that I can do this with Requests, but it only runs on Python 2.7:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.ripple.com/v1/accounts/rssc7gemsZBsseHxyb5NmjfYpJD6aUJirq/balances')
r.json()
```

In the former case, html is giving me data that I want, but it's not in a form I can parse. How can I turn the data I get from the server into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use urllib2:

```
import urllib2
import json
response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.ripple.com/v1/accounts/rssc7gemsZBsseHxyb5NmjfYpJD6aUJirq/balances')
html = response.read()
json_data = json.loads(html)
```